# SQL Server Table Parameter without defining fields

Tags: sql-server

I've built a SQL Server table from my C# code by taking the `ColumnNames` from a `DataTable` as it's derived from an Excel file I import.

This works fine; now I'd like to use SQL table I created in a separate stored procedure without using dynamic SQL because the query is fairly large and it's going to be a pain to maintain if I go that route.

I can't specify the columns in the stored procedure if I create a `Table` parameter because it's not a static set of columns, which is why I had to build the table dynamically from my C# code.

So I'm essentially looking to do something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_SprocName

    @TableName VARCHAR(50)

AS

SELECT Something FROM Somewhere R
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM @TableName HR
    WHERE Field = Whatever
) HR ON R.Field= HR.Field
```

However, I get the error to declare my `@Table` variable in my subquery.

Is there some way to get around this without using dynamic SQL?

Comment: Answer: no.....

Comment: As @MichałTurczyn stated, you can't use parameters for object names without dynamic sql. If you go the dynamic route, I suggest using quotename as well.

Comment: Something in your design sounds like it went horribly wrong.

Comment: @SeanLange: Please elaborate? Is there something wrong with building a table dynamically, based on your source, if you don't know how many fields it's going to have? Would you rather design a static solution and be fixing exceptions forever and a day?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn & scsimo: Thanks for the input. Guess I'll have to use dynamic SQL :(